# Data display problem - flask, python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Hi guys i have little problem, Got two models Person and Pet, i have two persons and 4 pets

What i want to display:

1. Person - and name of a pets
2. In the same view add a href with id of a person, after lick name of a Person and list of a pets in new view
   WHAT I HAVE SO FAR 
   ***MODELS:***

```
class Person(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='owner', lazy='joined')

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

 class Pet(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key= True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('person.id'))

    def __init__(self,name,owner_id):
        self.name = name
        self.owner_id = owner_id
```

WHAT I HAVE SO FAR ***VIEW:***

```
def list_item():
    # Grab a list of puppies from database.
    persons = Person.query.all()
    return render_template('list.html', persons=persons)
```

WHAT I HAVE SO FAR ***HTML:*** ( list.html )

```
{% for person in persons %}
<li>{{ person.name }} - {{ person.pets }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

OUTPUT:

```
   • Person1 - [<Pet 3>, <Pet 4>, <Pet 1>]
   • Person2 - [<Pet 2>]
```

and i want to have exess to artibutes like name in pets calling persons.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html template is `person.pets` a list of `Pet` objects. You can itererate over them with an aditional `for` loop to get the `Pet` objects and then the attributs of them:

```
{% for person in persons %}
<li>
    {{ person.name }} has the following pets:
    <ul>
        {% for pet in person.pets %}
        <li> {{ pet.name }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```